# How do I use an Excel cell inside of a SQL query using PowerShell?

Tags: sql, excel, powershell

Here's the scenario. I am going to be looping through thousands of Excel files and plucking out information and inserting it into a SQL database. So far I can loop through all of the files and spit out certain cells to the console. I can also insert a static value in the SQL insert statement. What I am having problems with is using the same cells I output to PowerShell console in the SQL insert query. I'm guessing it's just a syntax error.

This is the interesting bit. I've tried single quotes, no quotes, double quotes all over.

```
$cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO QuoteData (QuoteNumber) VALUES ($WorkSheet.Range("B8").Text)"
```

Comment: I assume that if you run `$WorkSheet.Range("B8").Text` on its own you get the value of that cell as output. so one quick workaround would be to first save that value into a new variable `$cellValue=$WorkSheet.Range("B8").Text;` and then use that variable in your SQL command `$cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO QuoteData (QuoteNumber) VALUES '$cellValue'";` note that I also added single quotes around the variable.

Comment: This sounds like an ETL process. Have you considered [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services)?

Comment: Thanks gpunktschmitz, putting it in a new variable did work. Ideally though I'd like to figure out how to get it to work without the variable. VonPryz, I've never used it before, but I will look into it. Part of this project is a learning experience so knowing how to do it both ways would be beneficial.

Comment: try this and let me know if it works `$cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO QuoteData (QuoteNumber) VALUES '$($WorkSheet.Range('B8').Text)'"`

Comment: That seems close, but it still doesn't like something. It says "Incorrect syntax near 'Mansfield'" which is the correct value for that cell in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

$cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO QuoteData (QuoteNumber) VALUES ('"+$WorkSheet.Range('B8').Text+"')"

Comment: It sure does! Thanks so much Rob. Thank you gpunktschmitz and vonPryz as well.